# Get the Row count of the result of a Stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Using `jdbcTemplate`, how would you get the Row count of the results of a stored procedure?

Like `queryForInt(...)` ? Without fetching the result of the stored procedure.

Example,

Just the count

12345

Comment: Without actually fetching the results?

Comment: Yes without fetching the results

Comment: Why not have the stored procedure send @@ROWCOUNT through an output parameter?